# Display default on page when list is empty in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to display a default message on page when list is empty.

```
<phone:PivotItem>
   <phone:PivotItem.Header>
      </phone:PivotItem.Header>
   <ScrollViewer>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" >
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <controls:ProcessRequest URLSource="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
```

I don't want to go in View Model to check whether list empty, then change the visibility of text block with message.

Is there any way to implement a generic method?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Visibility` of a `TextBox` by binding its `Visibility` property to the `collection.Count` property, and use a custom `IValueConverter` to switch `Visibility` depending on the count. This means your viewmodel isn't involved.